# Import a C++20 module from parent or sibling directory

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Given the project structure

```
src
  MyModule.cpp
test
  TestMyModule.cpp
```

How does one import MyModule in TestMyModule.cpp?

Edit: apparently a environment issue is making me unable to import it

My CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET FocusApp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

project ("App")
enable_testing()

add_executable (App "src/EntryPoint.ixx" "src/Time.ixx" )
add_executable(TestTime "src/Time.ixx" "test/TestTime.ixx" )

if((CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME STREQUAL PROJECT_NAME OR MYPROJECT_BUILD_TESTING) AND BUILD_TESTING)
    add_subdirectory(test)
endif()

add_test("testerino" TestTime.exe)
```

Comment: The module *system* doesn't know or care about directories. It's your *compiler* that has to know and care about them. So you need to tell it about those directories, which will vary from compiler to compiler and build-system to build-system.

Comment: You're right. But I can't find the issue with my CMakeList.txt, you happen to know what it is?

Comment: Appears CMake support is [beta at best](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18355)

Comment: @Erithax not all build system support modules. build2 supports it except on windows, msbuild supports only windows, meson has the start of something working.